# javascript return new array of unique elements with .filter()

Tags: javascript, comparison-operators

I have written code to return a new array containing only the unique elements of two seperate arrays. example: [1,2,3] and [1,2] will return 3. I have working code, however I would just like an explanation of why this works when using '!' before my return statement:

```
function diffArray(arr1, arr2) {
  return arr1.concat(arr2).filter(function(val){
    return !(arr1.indexOf(val) >= 0 && arr2.indexOf(val) >= 0)
  });
}

diffArray([1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
```

but this does not:

```
function diffArray(arr1, arr2) {
  return arr1.concat(arr2).filter(function(val){
    return arr1.indexOf(val) < 0 && arr2.indexOf(val) < 0
  });
}

diffArray([1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
```

I was under the impression that '!' would just invert the expression, so excluding it and using a '<' rather than '>=' should return the same value.

Comment: Think about what what happens to the `&&` operator. You recognize applying ! across your expression changes the comparisons but left the AND as is.

Answer (score 4):

According to [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws), the equivalent to the expression

```
!(arr1.indexOf(val) >= 0 && arr2.indexOf(val) >= 0)
```

is

```
(arr1.indexOf(val) < 0 || arr2.indexOf(val) < 0)
//                     ^^
```

Comment: Thanks for linking to the De Morgan ref.

Answer (score 2):

The opposite of

**a AND b are greater than 0**

is not

**a AND b are inferior to 0**

but

**a OR b are inferior to 0**

I believe this would work :

```
function diffArray(arr1, arr2) {
    return arr1.concat(arr2).filter(function(val){
        return arr1.indexOf(val) < 0 || arr2.indexOf(val) < 0
    });                            /*^^*/
}

diffArray([1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
```